# Delphi TcxDateEdit Time being deleted

Tags: delphi

We are using the Tcxdateedit component in Delphi 2007. The component works great on my Windows 10 machine and an old XP machine. However on my colleagues computer the time keeps getting deleted. She clicks the down arrow key and selects the date and time then clicks OK. The date and time is displayed correctly in the box but as soon as she leaves the component the time disappears. She gets the same outcome even if she just types in the date and time without using the drop down arrow.

The time is critical for us. Has anyone seen this before.

Thanks,
Maria

Comment: Naive code that takes the date and time as a string could be tripped up by regional and format settings causing behavior like this.

Comment: I think there is a property ShowTime (or something like that). Also 00:00 will be hidden.